# Get data from array that contains xmlrpcval object

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get int 98 from a example below?

```
$resp = $client->send($msg);
if ($resp->faultCode())
    echo 'Error: '.$resp->faultString();
else
    echo print_r($resp->value()->scalarval());
```

`print_r()` returns this:

```
Array ( [0] => xmlrpcval Object ( [me] => Array ( [int] => 98 ) [mytype] => 1 [_php_class] => ) ) 1
```

All I've been trying to do is get that `98` from `Array([int] => 98))` in a variable...

Comment: `$resp->value()->scalarval()[0]->me['int'] == 98`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be easier if the `print_r()` output was formatted and there is probably a better way using `xmlrpcval` but this will do it for the object:

```
$result = $resp->value()->scalarval();
$value  = $result[0]->me['int'];
```